# Is there a way to access the variables/fetch the assigned values of the caller class in a method of the called class?

Tags: java, class, static

This is similar to the question :
[Is there a way to access the variables of the calling class in a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396604/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-variables-of-the-calling-class-in-a-method)
But I am not quite able to get the exact answer.
What I am trying to do:

```
class A{
    m()
    {
        int a=8;
        new B.m1();

    }
}

class B{
    m1()
    {
         //Print the value of a of class A (i.e 8) here     
    }
}
```

**Constraints:** *Nothing in class A should be changed.Changes to be made in class B only! (such as putting B.m1(this) in class A etc. )*

Comment: inherit `class A` using extends and then print the value of `a`

Comment: @UmaKanth - That would make `B` an `A`. I don't think that's what the OP wants

Comment: @UmaKanth, it wouldn't help here since `a` is a method local variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. *Especially* since `a` is a local variable.

If `a` had been a field, there *might* have been a remote possibility to solve this using some reflection / stack trace hack.

Comment: Well, *technically* there could be some *Unsafe* way to do it, but that's out of scope of this question.

Comment: @Kayaman, to the extend of my knowledge, there is no way what so ever, to do it within the bounds of the Java Language Specification.

Comment: @Kayaman : yea...i don't care if it's unsafe (thread unsafe you mean right!). Just wondering if this is at all possible!

Comment: @SoumavaDas, I would guess Kayaman is referring to sun.misc.Unsafe etc. But neither with this (undocumented) class nor in a thread unsafe way is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

Read about 'this' keyword. But here it's not possible because you are talking about a local variable whose scope is just the method m()

Answer (score 0):

Given the scope of 'a', passing it as a parameter is the only way of accessing it.